# Simple JavaScript event listener not responding to events

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

The Stripe documentation provides the following sample JS code:

```
var cardholderName = document.getElementById('cardholder-name');
var cardButton = document.getElementById('card-button');

cardButton.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  stripe.createPaymentMethod('card', cardElement, {
    billing_details: {name: cardholderName.value}
  }).then(function(result) {
    if (result.error) {
      // Show error in payment form
    } else {
      // Otherwise send paymentMethod.id to your server (see Step 2)
      fetch('/ajax/confirm_payment', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ payment_method_id: result.paymentMethod.id })
      }).then(function(result) {
        // Handle server response (see Step 3)
        result.json().then(function(json) {
          handleServerResponse(json);
        })
      });
    }
  });
});
```

The code can be found at this URL: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/quickstart#collect-payment-method

However, in a test web page it does absolutely nothing whatsoever.

I stripped the code back to it's most basic form:

```
var cardButton = document.getElementById('card-button');

cardButton.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
    console.log('wub');
});
```

So, when I click the button I expect the console to log wub, however the console logs nothing.

This makes no sense to me as it was the exact code provided from Stripe.

Comment: remember: if you're using `.then()`, _always_ have a `.catch()` as well. Having said that, did you remember to mark your script as `defer` (since it operates on page content)

Comment: If the "basic" code doesn't work, that probably means it's executed **before** the DOM is ready or that the element does not exist.. Where is it executed?

Comment: At the bottom of the page.

Comment: surround the event with document ready,                                          $( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});

Comment: @JesseOrange mind sharing how the HTML is structured and where the script is included?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7trye1bf/ -- it works here. I also suspect that the javascript is running before the `#card-button` is ready

Comment: _"it's executed before the DOM is ready or that the element does not exist"_ - Hence it would throw a `TypeError: cardButton is null`

Comment: @Andres it should, indeed. I missed the part "however the console logs nothing". However, I have no other guesses other than that.

Comment: I appreciate all the feedback, this is why I was perplexed.

Comment: As you can see from the comments your question isn't clear as this code should work _as-is_. Please add a [mcve] which shows the actual problem.